# Is it possible to postpone execution of some javascript function until browser event is fully processed?

Tags: javascript, dom

For example I need to execute some function when onblur/onfocus event is processed (one element has lost focus and other has taken focus).

To be more specific I have something like the following.

```
<div id="foo" tabIndex="1" onblur="document.getElementById('bar').style.display = 'none';">foo</div>
<div id="bar" tabIndex="2" onclick="alert('bar');">bar</div>
<div>stuff</div>
```

Let's suppose element 'foo' is focused. When 'foo' loses focus I should hide element 'bar'. But if I click on 'bar' I should see alert. It doesn't work because after event onblur is processed then element 'bar' is invisible, and neither onclick nor onfocus occur.

Comment: Do you want to do this to specific elements? Or is it something like "anytime an input loses focus and a link gains it"?

Comment: Also, some HTML might be helpful in more accurately answering your question.

Comment: One suggestion, you should generally avoid embedding event handlers within the tag. Instead initialize them all within the script.

Answer (score 2):

Just manage it in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var blurTimeout;
function Blur(el)
{
    blurTimeout = setTimeout(function() 
    {
        SomeFunction();
    }, 500);
}
function Focus(el)
{
    if (blurTimeout)
        cancelTimeout(blurTimeout);
}
</script>
<input id="input1" type="text" onblur="Blur(this);" />
<input id="input2" type="text" onfocus="Focus(this);" />
```

**EDIT:**

Updated. Now you need only attach the Focus handler to one element.

The Blur handler sets up a 1/2 second timeout which will call `SomeFunction()`. The Focus handler cancels the timeout to prevent the function call. You can adjust the delay to make it appear more immediate, but given your requirement, it must be asynchronous.

**This is a rather kludgy solution. If I found myself writing this in production code, I would rethink the design or (if possible) revisit the requirements.**

Comment: Actually I don't want to subscribe all elements on by page to onfocus event. I just need to execute my function in all cases when element 'foo' lost focus except the one when element 'bar' got focus.

Comment: But that's what this examples *does*.

Comment: In this example function will be executed only if input2 got focus, my situation is different, function should be executed if any element got focus except input2.

Comment: Updated. But this is an ugly solution. You may want to reconsider what it is you actually want to accomplish. Is it possible to rewrite `SomeFunction()` to work even when focus is applied to input2?

Comment: The following snippet I have found in dojo (dijit.form.ComboBox)

if(doSearch){
 // need to wait a tad before start search so that the event
 // bubbles through DOM and we have value visible
 setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this, "_startSearchFromInput"),1);
}

So, I suppose the way 'setTimeout(someFunction, 1)' is not so bad. We have only one thread in javascript, so execution will be postponed until event processing is done and thread is released.